# How can I change the default installation directory from 'root' to 'home' when updating and installing from packet manager?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, opensuse

I am running OpenSuse. Everything gets installed in the root directory, and it's full already.I got my setup installed as:

- 20gb for root
- 16gb for swap
- 62gb for opt
- 200gb for home

Comment: Something is not okay by you, 20gb should be far as enough for a root partition.

Comment: I think you wanted to write "swap" instead "switch", these things mean very different things ("switch" is a layer2 routing device, "swap" means to exchange something to a different one, OR the virtual memory written temporarily into disk on optimiziation reasons).

Answer (score 0):

> Everything gets installed in the root directory

I assume you mean "in the root partition". The "root directory" is the home directory of *root*, the privileged user.

> the following sub drives

You probably mean "partitions".

> 16gb for switch

I assume it's "swap".

You cannot install packages from the Package Manager on the "home" partition; that's the space devoted to your personal files and data.

Since you are clearly inexperienced with Linux (no offense intended), the best you can do is to ask the person who did the partitioning for you and require they expand the root partition, possibly by adding a disk.

Answer (score 0):

First, 20GB is far as enough for any system installation. This was the reason, why your suse set this to default.

*Something is likely eating your root partition*, I don't know what is it, but probably you are doing there something what you shouldn't! Maybe you are using your root account for everything? The home of the root user is in /root, which is now on your home partition. Check a `du -sh /root`, what it says?

*You should do everything as an ordinary user and switch to root only if it is unavoidable. The ordinary users have their datas in the `/home`, which is your large, and likely currently unused partition.*

#### In general

Partitioning disks is a mainly obsolete thing today. I install my linux workstations always without partitioning, everything is going into a single, full-disk root. You can read more about it in my other answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/629452/200053).

Unfortunately, SuSE doesn't follow this, which is explainable.

If you have multiple disks, a server system, virtualization or other hardcore thing, then you could use [Logical Volume Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), but it is likely not your case.

In your case, the only reason to have multiple partitions if you share the machine with another OS (typically, win + linux dual-boot systems are the most common).